# How can I change the number of iterations from 11 to 3?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, programming, code-review

The simplified example given below currently uses 11 iterations just for drawing at most 3 stems (vertical segments). It seems that my code is not efficient enough so I want to reduce the number of iteration from 11 to 3. Is it possible?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Ruler[1]{%
\FPeval\Start{trunc(#1*10:0)}%
\FPeval\Stop{trunc(#1+1:1)}%
\bgroup
\psset{xunit=.1\psxunit}
\begin{pspicture}[linecap=1](0,-.5)(10,.5)
    \psline(10,0)
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\i=\Start+1}{11}{%
        \pst@mod{\i}{10}\rem
        \ifnum\rem=0
            \psline(\ix,0)(\ix,9pt)
            \uput[90](\ix,6pt){\the\numexpr\i/10}
        \else
            \pst@mod{\i}{5}\rem
            \ifnum\rem=0
                \psline(\ix,0)(\ix,4pt)
            \fi
        \fi
    }
        \psline[linecolor=red]{<-}(0,-2pt)(0,-10pt)
        \uput[-90](0,-6pt){\textcolor{red}{#1}}
        \psline[linecolor=red]{<-}(10,-2pt)(10,-10pt)
        \uput[-90](10,-6pt){\textcolor{red}{\Stop}}
\end{pspicture}\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Ruler{3.0}
\Ruler{3.1}
\Ruler{3.5}
\Ruler{3.6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Edit

`\Ruler{x}` will draw a truncated ruler of length `1cm` starting from `x`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please tell us where you got the code you seem to be not entirely happy with?

Comment: I understand that. What I would like to know is if you wrote it yourself or copied it from somewhere (which is fine but the source will be [useful for writing an answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7725/121799)). And I am wondering if you would also be open to Ti*k*Z solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `multido` for that.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Ruler[1]{%
\FPeval\Start{trunc(#1*10:0)}%
\FPeval\Stop{trunc(#1+1:1)}%
\bgroup
\psset{xunit=.1\psxunit}
\begin{pspicture}[linecap=1](0,-.5)(10,.5)
    \psline(10,0)
    \pst@mod{\Start}{10}\rem
    \FPeval\xStart{trunc(10-\rem:0)}%
    \psline(\xStart,0)(\xStart,9pt)
    \FPeval\xLab{trunc(#1:0)}%
    \uput[90](\xStart,6pt){\the\numexpr\xLab+1}
    \ifnum\rem=0
        \psline(0,0)(0,9pt)
        \psline(10,0)(10,9pt)
        \uput[90](0,6pt){\xLab}
        \psline(5,0)(5,4pt)
    \else
        \ifnum\rem=5
            \psline(0,0)(0,4pt)
            \psline(10,0)(10,4pt)
        \else
            \FPeval\xMid{trunc(10-\rem+5:0)}%
            \pst@mod{\xMid}{10}\xMid%
            \psline(\xMid,0)(\xMid,4pt)
        \fi
    \fi
    \psline[linecolor=red]{<-}(0,-2pt)(0,-10pt)
    \uput[-90](0,-6pt){\textcolor{red}{#1}}
    \psline[linecolor=red]{<-}(10,-2pt)(10,-10pt)
    \uput[-90](10,-6pt){\textcolor{red}{\Stop}}
\end{pspicture}\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Ruler{3.0}
\Ruler{3.1}
\Ruler{3.5}
\Ruler{3.6}
\end{document}
```

[image]